# how to find an element in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json

i have the following query:

```
$simplequery = array('type'=>'/travel/travel_destination',
                     'id'=>$_POST["hcity"],
                     'name' => null,
                     'tourist_attractions' => array(
                         array('/common/topic/article'=>array(array('guid'=>null)),
                               '/common/topic/image'=>array(array('guid'=>null))
                         )
                     )
);

$queryarray = array('q1' => array('query' => $simplequery));
$jsonquerystr = json_encode($queryarray);
//echo $jsonquerystr;
#run the query 
$apiendpoint = "http://www.freebase.com/api/service/mqlread?queries";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$apiendpoint=$jsonquerystr");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$jsonresultstr = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$temp = str_replace("#", "", $jsonresultstr);
$resultarray = json_decode($temp, true);
```

I want to take the guid string of the '/common/topic/image' array. It is a multidimensional array and i can't find out how to do it.
I tried writting

```
$result = $resultarray["q1"]["result"]["tourist_atractions"]['/common/topic/image'];
```

but it  is not working. can you please help me? thanks

Comment: Can you add a `print_r($resultarray)` so that we can see what format the array is output in?

Comment: have you tried doing a print_r($resultarray); after the last line to check how the array is being returned? that would make things way clearer for you.

Comment: Is your misspell of "attractions" a copy/paste error or does that exist in your actual code?

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $resultarray["q1"]["result"]["tourist_attractions"]['/common/topic/image'][0]['guid'];
```

Comment: finally the main problem was the misspelling of the word "attractions".

Answer (score 0):

First guess? You misspelt "attractions":

```
$resultarray["q1"]["result"]["tourist_attractions"]['/common/topic/image'];
```